# I am getting this error "Failed processing manifest "

Tags: android, android-manifest

So I'm getting this error:

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  C:\Users\tomas\AndroidStudioProjects\app\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:11: error: '@android:' is incompatible with attribute fullBackupContent (attr) reference|boolean.
error: failed processing manifest.
```

on my app, I'm currently developing on android studio.

Comment: try to clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113305/cannot-build-an-apk-due-to-problems-with-androidmanifest-xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have wrongly used `@android/name_of_file_for_backup_rules` in place of `@xml/`.
The fullBackupContent attribute points to an XML file that contains backup rules. For example:

```
<application ...
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/my_backup_rules">
</application>
```

The my_backup_rules.xml has to be created in res/xml for backup rules.
For Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<full-backup-content>
    <include domain="sharedpref" path="."/>
    <exclude domain="sharedpref" path="device.xml"/>
</full-backup-content>
```

Refer to for more info : [Back up user data with Auto Backup developers.google.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup):

Answer (score 0):

> `@android:`' is incompatible with attribute `fullBackupContent` (attr)

In `fullBackupContent` of `<application` tag of the `AndroidManifest.xml`, you've set something like this:

```
@android/anything
```

<sub>Or just `@android`</sub>

Which is not true and it only takes boolean like `true` or `false`.

Check the error:

```
reference|boolean.
```